# axiom 2 of Serre's FAC definition of algebraic variety

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

If you read Serre's FAC you will notice the definition of algebraic variety X (section 34 page 40),  http://achinger.impan.pl/fac/fac.pdf

axiom 2: $\Delta= \{(x,x) \mid x \in X\} \subset X \times X$ is closed in the induced topology of X $\times$ X.

In the product topology (which looks like the induced topology... but I may be wrong here) $\Delta$ closed iff X Hausdorff

He later uses the Zariski topology on X. But we know the Zariski topology is not Hausdorff.

What is wrong with my interpretation of the induced topology?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the topology on $X \times X$ is not the product topology when we use the Zariski topology. You can think of $\mathbb A^2 = \mathbb A^1 \times \mathbb A^1$ for convince yourself of this fact.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing... but I'm not **convinced** about the topology. Can you give an example of what the open sets look like in $\mathbb{A}^2$?

Comment: have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128102/zariski-topology-question

Comment: The answers the users did contains all the informations you need. The open set in $\mathbb A^2$ are complement of finite union of curves and points. You should think a bit more about the curve defined by $(x,x)$ in $\mathbb A^2$ or a parabola for example.

Comment: hold on... why are we putting the Zariski topology on X $\times$ X in the first place?

Comment: I think Serre is trying to say that we just need **some** topology **finer than the product topology** such that axiom 2 is satisfied. So we could actually pick more than one topology such that the diagonal is closed (certainly not the product topology) on X $\times$ X ?? What do you think?

Comment: No. We are in the category of algebraic varieties so we **always** take the Zariski topology. Maybe you should read more about algebraic geometry before reading FAC ?

Comment: Well I don't know where such an assumption is written.

Comment: I believe Serre is recalling some stuff about algebraic varieties before giving this "axiom 2", and he's writing all the necessary precisions. In particular there is a remark that the Zariski topology on product spaces. If everything is still not clear I would suggest to study a bit more algebraic geometry before reading this article.